# How to display the entries according to the vocuher no

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Expected Result[image: Expected result]Purchaseitem table structure[image: purchaseitem table]Purchasebill table strucuture[image: purchase bill table] Current output[image]I am preparing register that inputs from date and to date from the user according to the date it has to print the entries according to the billno...I am using two queries for this one for displaying voucher no, bill date and party name and another query for item name quantity.Query1 works fine I am having the problem with the query variable it printing all the entries present on the database from the user provided from date and to date but I have to print from date and to date according to the voucher no. Help me to solve this issue...
Controller Code:

```
$this->db->where('billdate >=', $newDate);
    $this->db->where('billdate <=', $newDate2);
    $this->db->from('purchaseitem');
        $this->db->order_by("vno", "asc");
        $this->db->join('purchasebill', 'purchasebill.no = purchaseitem.billno','left outer');
        $this->db->join('itemmaster','itemmaster.itcode = purchaseitem.Product_Code','left outer');
        $query = $this->db->get('')->result_array();
        $data['query'] = $query;
        $this->db->where('date >=', $newDate);
        $this->db->where('date <=', $newDate2);
        $this->db->select();
        $this->db->from('purchasebill');
        $this->db->order_by('voucherno');
        $this->db->group_by('voucherno');
        $this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = purchasebill.partyname','left outer');
        $query = $this->db->get('')->result_array();
        $data['query1'] = $query;
        $this->load->view('Receipt_View1',$data);
```

View code:

```
<?php $rowcount = 1 ?>                          
        <?php foreach ($query1 as $row): ?>

<tr>
                                            <td><?=$rowcount;?></td>
                                            <td><?=$row['voucherno'];?></td>
                                            <td><?=$row['date'];?></td>
                                            <td><?=$row['PName'];?></td>
                                            <?php $rowcount +=1?>
                                            <?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>
                                                <tr>
                                            <td><?=$row['Prdtname'];?></td>
                                            <td><?=$row['Qty'];?></td>
                                            <td><?=$row['bundle'];?></td>

                                            <?php endforeach ?> 
                                            <?php endforeach ?> 
</tr></tr>
```

Comment: Please show us your tables schema, example data, current result and expected result.

Comment: okey sir..i will add it

Comment: It is not relevant to my question @Strawberry

Comment: I'm not convinced that you're qualified to make such an assessment. But good luck.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by using voucher no on the array
Controller Code:

```
public function Purchase_Register1()
{
    $startdate = $this->input->post('SDate');
$enddate = $this->input->post('EDate');
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $startdate);
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
$date2 = str_replace('/', '-', $enddate);
$newDate2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date2));
$data['startdate'] = $startdate;
$data['enddate'] = $enddate;
if( ($this->input->post('all')) && ($this->input->post('item')) ) {
    $this->db->select('parmaster.PName, purchasebill.voucherno, purchaseitem.billdate, purchasebill.partyname, purchaseitem.prdtname, purchaseitem.quantity,purchaseitem.bundle');
    $this->db->from('purchasebill');
    $this->db->join('purchaseitem', 'purchasebill.voucherno = purchaseitem.vno');
    $this->db->join('parmaster', 'parmaster.pcode = purchasebill.partyname');
    $this->db->where('purchaseitem.billdate >=', $newDate);
    $this->db->where('purchaseitem.billdate <=', $newDate2);
    $this->db->order_by('purchasebill.voucherno');

    $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    if($result){
        $finalArray = array();
        $checkArray = array();
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            if(in_array($value['voucherno'], $checkArray)){
                $finalArray[$value['voucherno']][] = $value;
            } else {
                $checkArray[] = $value['voucherno'];
                $finalArray[$value['voucherno']][] = $value;
            }
        }
        $data['query'] = $finalArray;
        $this->load->view('Whole_Sales/Purchase_Register2', $data);
        //echo '<pre>';print_r($finalArray);echo '</pre>';exit();
    } 
}else if( ($this->input->post('selected')) && ($this->input->post('businessType')) && ($this->input->post('item')) ) {
    $name = $this->input->post('businessType');
    $this->db->select('parmaster.PName, purchasebill.voucherno, purchaseitem.billdate, purchasebill.partyname, purchaseitem.prdtname, purchaseitem.quantity,purchaseitem.bundle');
    $this->db->from('purchasebill');
    $this->db->join('purchaseitem', 'purchasebill.voucherno = purchaseitem.vno');
    $this->db->join('parmaster', 'parmaster.pcode = purchasebill.partyname');
    $this->db->where('purchaseitem.billdate >=', $newDate);
    $this->db->where('purchaseitem.billdate <=', $newDate2);
    $this->db->where('PName',$name);
    $this->db->order_by('purchasebill.voucherno');
    $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    if($result){
        $finalArray = array();
        $checkArray = array();
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            if(in_array($value['voucherno'], $checkArray)){
                $finalArray[$value['voucherno']][] = $value;
            } else {
                $checkArray[] = $value['voucherno'];
                $finalArray[$value['voucherno']][] = $value;
            }
        }
        $data['query'] = $finalArray;
        $this->load->view('Whole_Sales/Purchase_Register2', $data);
```

View Page:

```
    <?php
    $totalQuantity = 0;
    $totalBundle = 0;
     $rowcount = 1;
    foreach ($query as $key => $value){
        $counter = 0;
?>
        <?php
        foreach ($value as $sub_key => $sub_value) {
            if($counter == 0) {
                $totalQuantity = $totalQuantity + $sub_value['quantity'];
                $totalBundle = $totalBundle + $sub_value['bundle'];
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $rowcount?>
                    <td><?php echo $sub_value['voucherno'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $sub_value['billdate'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $sub_value['PName'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $sub_value['prdtname'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $sub_value['quantity'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $sub_value['bundle'];?></td>
                    <?php $rowcount +=1?>
                </tr>
            <?php
            $counter++;
            } else {
                $totalQuantity = $totalQuantity + $sub_value['quantity'];
                $totalBundle = $totalBundle + $sub_value['bundle'];
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo $sub_value['prdtname'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $sub_value['quantity'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $sub_value['bundle'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            } // else
        } // foreach
    }
    ?>
```